# How to use SAML 2.0 response for specific DNN user role group authentication and authorization?

Tags: single-sign-on, dotnetnuke, saml, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

I am looking for refrerance implemention/code snipet to sign-in external user to DNN Evoq web site using SAML 2.0 response.

In my case, our corporate web site ie www.nondnnsite.com is a owning a identity provider. SSO page built under this site. There is another web site i.e. www.dnnsite.com which is anonymous to everybody. Only content manager and editor can login to www.dnnsite.com using standard login form.

Now a request came where we need to use identity provider of www.nondnnsite.com and generate SAML 2.0 response after successful authentication in www.nondnnsite.com and allow that user to access "Page-1" in www.dnnsite.com

Which is a standard scenario for SSO

Now i need help to understand how to parse this SAML response and let the authenticated user access the "Page-1" which is only accessible to role group "externally authenticated user"

Please help in this regards, if you can point out to some sample source code it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I'm using [Componentspace](https://componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net) to implement SAML SSO, with success.

Good luck!